# sql group_concat fizzle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many to many relationship with an intermediary table:

```
table puppy          table color          table color_join (join table)

puppy_name | ID      color  | ID          puppy_ID | color_ID
---------------      -----------          -------------------
a          | 1       color1 | 1           1        | 1
b          | 2       color2 | 2           1        | 2
                     color3 | 3           2        | 3
                     color4 | 4           2        | 4
```

`ID`'s are primary keys, while `puppy_ID, color_ID` are foreign keys.

My query is this:

```
SELECT p.name, c.color as color
FROM puppy p
JOIN color_join cj ON p.ID = cj.puppy_ID
JOIN color c ON c.ID = cj.color_ID
```

It returns this:

```
puppy_name | color
------------------
a          | 1
a          | 2
b          | 3
b          | 4
```

I want the colors to be be grouped up like so:

```
puppy_name | color
------------------
a          | 1,2
b          | 3,4
```

To that end i have tried a `group_concat( distinct c.color)` however i get only 1 row back with the color column containing all the colors:

```
puppy_name | color
--------------------
a          | 1,2,3,4
```

If i put a `where p.id = 1` clause in the query with the `group_concat( distinct c.color)` i get only one row still, however the colors and their numbers are correct.

```
puppy_name | color
--------------------
a          | 1,2
```

How can i accomplish what i want?

Comment: @i tried, but i get only one row still. Got an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by `p.name`.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, group_concat(distinct c.color) as colors
FROM puppy p
JOIN color_join cj ON p.ID = cj.puppy_ID
JOIN color c ON c.ID = cj.color_ID
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

When you group then aggregate functions like `group_concat` are applied to each group and not the whole recordset.

Comment: Let me give it a go, but as a first note, grouping by the name field is not a good choice. There can be multiple puppies with the same name. Perhaps a group by `p.ID`.